# Spring Integration Test inject PersistenceContext

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, dependency-injection

I'm integrating Hibernate Search in our Spring MVC Application.

Therefore we have a "BuildSearchIndex" Class which is called at the Start of the application to create the Search Index:

```
@Component
public class BuildSearchIndex implements ApplicationListener {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "entityManagerFactory")
    private EntityManager _entityManager;

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationEvent event) {
        try {
            FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(_entityManager);
            fullTextEntityManager.createIndexer().startAndWait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("An error occurred trying to build the search index: " + e.toString());
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

In the Normal Application run everything is fine.

But when I try to start my Integration test, I allways get a IllegalArgumentException, that the EntityManager is null.

The Class Definition of our IntegrationTest looks like this:

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@WebAppConfiguration
@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback = false)
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
public class DummyServiceIntTest extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests {

}
```

How do I inject the Entity Manager corretly in this Integration Test?

Comment: from the information most probable suspect is "test" profile. How is it different from default profile?

Comment: It just has another Database authentication in it and disables our LDAP connection, but I don't think This is the reason, because since I added the BuildSearchIndex class all Integration Tests are failing, not only the ones from this TestClass but all...

Comment: They will all fail if the context cannot be loaded, so that isn't that strange. Do you configure your own `EntityManagerFactory`? Also try removing the `unitName` from the annotation, when using a single one that isn't needed and it should point to the name of the unit and now it appears to be pointing to the name of the bean.